# Different objects in different boxes

Tags: combinatorics

We want to distribute 12 balls in 5 boxes, such that there are 3 identical white balls, 5 identical red balls and 4 identical green balls.
My answer would be:
Distribute white balls first: $\displaystyle\binom{7}{3}$
Then red: $\displaystyle\binom{9}{5}$
Then green: $\displaystyle\binom{8}{4}$
And multiply them all together.
However, the given answer is $\displaystyle\binom{12}{3,5,4}$, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: The given answer indeed makes no sense.  In particular, the given answer makes no reference to the number of boxes and so can not possibly be correct... the same logic used would have supposedly given the same answer if it were 5 boxes as if it were 100 boxes as if it were 100000 boxes, but we know that the more boxes the more ways there are to distribute.

Comment: Also to add, your solution works if boxes can be empty.